# Segment Tree with lazy propagation Time limit problem

Tags: c++, segment-tree, lazy-propagation

The following is the implementation of http://www.spoj.pl/problems/LITE/ using Segment Tree's with lazy propagation. I am new to segment trees and I cannot understand why I am getting TLE. Could someone please look at it and help me correct my error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#define MAX 100000
using namespace std;
int M[2*MAX+1];
int flag[2*MAX+1];
int count;
void refresh(int begin,int end,int n)
{
    M[n] = end-begin+1 - M[n];
    flag[n]=0;
    flag[n*2] =!flag[n*2];
    flag[n*2+1] =!flag[n*2+1];
}
void update(int begin,int end,int i,int j,int n=1)
{
    if(flag[n])
    {
        refresh(begin,end,n);
    }
    if(begin>=i && end<=j)
    {
        if(!flag[n])
        {
            refresh(begin,end,n);
        }
        flag[n] = 0;
        return;
    }
    else if(begin>=end)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int mid = (begin+end)>>1;
        if(i<=mid)
        {
            update(begin,mid,i,j,n*2);
        }
        if(j>mid)
        {
            update(mid+1,end,i,j,n*2+1);
        }
        if(flag[2*n])
        {
            refresh(begin,mid,2*n);
        }
        if(flag[2*n+1])
        {
            refresh(mid+1,end,2*n+1);
        }
        M[n] = M[n*2]+ M[n*2+1];
    }
}
int query(int begin,int end,int i,int j,int n=1)
{
    if(flag[n])
    {
        refresh(begin,end,n);
    }
    if(begin>=i && end<=j)
    {
        return M[n];
    }
    if(begin>=end)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int mid = (begin+end)>>1;
    int l=0,r=0;
    if(i<=mid)
    {
        l = query(begin,mid,i,j,n*2);
    }
    if(j>mid)
    {
        r = query(mid+1,end,i,j,n*2+1);
    }
    if(flag[2*n])
    {
        refresh(begin,mid,2*n);
    }
    if(flag[2*n+1])
    {
        refresh(mid+1,end,2*n+1);
    }
    M[n] = M[n*2]+ M[n*2+1];
    return l+r;
}
int main()
{
    memset(M,0,sizeof M);
    int n,m,a,b,c;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
        if(a==0)
        {
            update(1,n,b,c);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d\n",query(1,n,b,c));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What input causes your program to fail?

Comment: I tried getting correct outputs via a brute force approach complexity O(m*n) and matching those generated by my segment tree approach. But that seems to be working correctly on my system and I dont get TLE since SPOJ uses a slower processor

Comment: tried reading a block at a time and parsing the block? maybe the IO is the bottleneck

Comment: I did a little digging at SPOJ forums it turns out that I am not using lazy propagation at all. If we were to update range [1,8] we would effectively have to update every node in the tree. Lazy propagation means that we would only update node [1,8] and leave a flag that says that it's children need to be updated. Then when we have to query deeper than [1,8] we push the update down to the children, along with the flag. This way we only update when needed.

Comment: http://www.spoj.pl/forum/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=8296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M[node]^=1;` might be faster than `M[node] = (M[node]==0)?1:0;`, and `(begin+end)>>1` faster than `(begin/end)/2`, but not very relevant

LE: Try if making  the recursive functions inline will run faster. I think it unravels the recursion a couple of times and works a little bit faster. Maybe sending the parameters as references will make it run faster, try that out. If the test cases are chosen properly you still shouldn't be able to pass the tests with this trickery, but it helps sometimes.

Comment: I tried that , it ran a few more test files than my original program but still TLE

Comment: I don't think you need 300k elements, 200k+1 should be enough for this

Comment: I made the changes still it gives TLE and modifying the function call to inline did not work.